# Rake Abort Error with no answer other than head to the wall . Repeat if necessary

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I am the intrepid little programmer that could. I began programming rails five weeks ago and I have been stuck on the same error for that entire time. It goes like this. I have mysql application installed, have the latest rails (2.3.5), ruby (1.8.6), and mysql (5.1.40).

I created a perfectly beautiful database and table with content in rails several times, same thing just to make sure. It's there. It works.

Then I go into my database.yml and make sure my login/password root access database is mysql everything good. Green light.

Then I do a rake db:migrate..

and I get this

```
    rake aborted!
    undefined method `generate_best_match=' for ActionController::Routing:Module


trace statement

(in /Users/johnsmith/Sites/rails/music_library2)
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
undefined method `generate_best_match=' for ActionController::Routing:Module
/Users/johnsmith/Sites/rails/music_library2/config/initializers/new_rails_defaults.rb:14
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in `load_without_new_constant_marking'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in `load'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in `load'
/Users/johnsmith/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.3/lib/initializer.rb:622:in `load_application_initializers'
/Users/johnsmith/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.3/lib/initializer.rb:621:in `each'
/Users/johnsmith/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.3/lib/initializer.rb:621:in `load_application_initializers'
/Users/johnsmith/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.3/lib/initializer.rb:176:in `process'
/Users/johnsmith/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.3/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
/Users/johnsmith/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.3/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
/Users/johnsmith/Sites/rails/music_library2/config/environment.rb:9
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Users/johnsmith/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.3/lib/tasks/misc.rake:4
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `execute'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:607:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:596:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
/usr/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/bin/rake:19
```

And seriously, no deals..

For five weeks..

What is a dude to do? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is caused by not using the correct mySQL version. In my case, 32-bit. Once I installed the 32-bit mySQL, and used the 32-bit gem, this worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Is this relevant? [Re: Deploying Error: undefined method 'generate_best_match='](http://www.highdots.com/forums/1283302-post3.html)

Comment: Or more, specifically, how do I find out if I'm running two versions, and if thats the case, prevent them from running against each other?

Answer (score 0):

Try commenting out the line:

ActionController::Routing.generate_best_match = false

in config/initializers/new_rails_defaults.rb

You lose some routing changes introduced in 2.3.4, but at least it might get your app running.

Comment: Hmm.. I got this..

(in /Users/johnsmith/Sites/rails/music_library2)
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _mysql_init
  Referenced from: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/lib/mysql_api.bundle
  Expected in: dynamic lookup

dyld: Symbol not found: _mysql_init
  Referenced from: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/lib/mysql_api.bundle
  Expected in: dynamic lookup

Trace/BPT trap